# Understanding "public" / "private" in typescript class

Tags: typescript

In the below type script code , irrespective of whether name is "public" or
"private" , java script code that is generated is same.

So my question is, how to decide when the constructor parameter should be
public or private ?

```
// typescript code
class Animal {  
constructor( public name: string) {     
}

}

// generated JS code
var Animal = (function () {
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
return Animal;
}());
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have any notion of private/public. But TypeScript does. So, if you make the name private, the rest of your **TypeScript** code won't be allowed by the TypeScript compiler to access the field, whereas if it's public, it will.

Comment: For those who are implementing Angular with Typescript, it's worth mentioning that public or private will work with data-binding and directives. However, some IDE's  like VS Code shows an error when the variable is private.

Comment: @JBNizet What about the compiled javascript?  Would compiled javascript code be able to access private members?  (For example, when running an in-line javascript interpreter on javascript already compiled from typescript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> java script code that is generated is same

They produce the same JavaScript but don't have the same semantics as far as the type is concerned.

The `private` member can only be accessed from inside the class whereas `public` can be excessed externally.

## More

The differences are covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html#access-modifiers

## Another example

```
let foo = 123;
```

will generate the same ES5 as

```
const foo = 123;
```

However in the first case `let foo = 123;foo = 456` will compile fine but `const foo = 123; foo = 456` will result in a compile time error.

Answer (score 19):

The public, private, protected access modifiers, as you have discovered, don't actually affect the final outputted code. What they *do* affect is the type checking at compile time.

#### What do they actually do?

As their names suggest, the `public` and `private` modifiers limit what can access the class member. Their is also a third modifier in the clan, `protected`.

The **private** modifier only allows a class member (variable or method) to be accessed *within that class*.

The **protected** modifier allows everything the `private` modifier does, and also allows other classes that extend that class to use it.

Finally, the **public** modifier makes it so anything can access the class also has access to the public class property.

For a more in-depth explanation and examples, take a look at the official TypeScript Handbook's [explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers).

#### If it all compiles the same, why should I use the modifiers?!

Using the modifiers will enable the compiler to make sure that your code isn't using things that it shouldn't be using. This is the same reasoning behind using types in the first place, it makes it harder to make mistakes that shouldn't be able to be made in the first place! As an added bonus, if your text editor has TypeScript support, it will also use the access modifiers when showing you autocomplete values for variables and methods.

Answer (score 1):

In ESnext, private class **fields** are defined using a hash # prefix:

```
class MyClass {
  a = 1;          // .a is public
  #b = 2;         // .#b is private
  static #c = 3;  // .#c is private and static
  incB() {
    this.#b++;
  }
}

const m = new MyClass();
m.incB(); // runs OK
m.#b = 0; // error - private property cannot be modified outside class
```

*Note:
there’s no way to define private **methods, getters** and **setters**.

but a proposal is there https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods