# TypeScript: use private or public in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript world, and I've seen examples with this to deal with injected objects and set it to a property of the component (this.anything)

First with public and setting by hand to this.nav

```
export class XPTO {
   constructor(public nav: NavController) {
      this.nav = nav;
   }
}
```

and this, with private

```
export class XPTO {
   constructor(private nav: NavController) {
      //this.nav is nav?
   }
}
```

in both cases after construct the object this.nav is a NavController object.
What are the differences of both implementations? Or this is the same when compiled to plain javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding "public" / "private" in typescript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713052/understanding-public-private-in-typescript-class)

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't do a good job of answering the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually in your first example the explicit assignment is not needed at all:

```js
export class XPTO {
   constructor(public nav: NavController) {
       // This line is not required when we have an access modifier (private/public) on the constructor parameter(s)
       // this.nav = nav;
       this.someFunction();
   }
   someFunction(){
       console.log(this.nav); // Prints out the NavController.
   }
}
```

Whenever you specify public or private on a constructor parameter a corresponding public/private variable is created on the class and filled with the value of the parameter.

So really, the only difference of the two code samples is that one is private and the other one is public.

The resulting JavaScript will be the same. However, the compiler will throw an error, if you are trying to access private variables in your code.

Answer (score 3):

`public` and `private`, as a lot of Typescript features, are only TypeScript modifiers. I'm not sure the compiler names these variables exactly the same, but from a JavaScript point of view, the code will be essentially the same.

The interest of Typescript is to give you features like type checking, it doesn't necessarily always modifies the outputted code.